# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, in-app-purchase, uikit

I am trying to add in app purchases to my xCode application, and i get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier:
>   (null)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x184bf82d8 0x19641c0e4 0x184bf8218 0x189597210 0x100066fa8 0x100067018 0x18966d404 0x1896564e0
>   0x18966cda0 0x18966ca2c 0x189665f68 0x18963918c 0x1898da324
>   0x1896376a0 0x184bb0240 0x184baf4e4 0x184bad594 0x184ad92d4
>   0x18e2ef6fc 0x18969efac 0x100069600 0x196a9aa08) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have tried running my application using both IOS Simulator and using my iPhone Device.

Full ViewController.swift code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate{

    var product:SKProduct!

    @IBOutlet weak var lastmanstandingButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var upgradeProButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        lastmanstandingButton.enabled = false
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        let products = response.products
        if (products.count != 0)
        {
            product = products[0] as! SKProduct;
            //productInfo.text = product.localizedTitle + "\n" + product.localizedDescription
        }
    }

    func getProductInfo(){
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:"com.mi.yaya.inapp1");
            let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self;
            request.start()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func upgradeProButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product);
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
    }

    func unlockProFeatures(){
        lastmanstandingButton.enabled = true
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    self.unlockProFeatures();
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .Failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .Restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tutorial used for IAP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnRO87_2GpQ

**EDIT:** In the iTunes Connect i have added the In-App Purchases in the Application i am creating. It says: Status: Ready to Submit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not setting the product identifier properly. Check where you are calling `getProductInfo` and if the ID is being properly set. Also check the sequence of your method calls and ensure that you send the ID in the right moment.

I would like to point to some lines that you might want to improve:

- you should set `product` as an optional because if your request does not return a value your application will crash
- `productsRequest` is not a good method name. Instead you can use `requestProducts`

Comment: The productID is correct. I have even copy/pasted the productID from iTunes Connect IAP, and into the xCode project. I cannot see what is wrong here.

Comment: I am sure you are setting the correct ID but check if it is sent correctly by setting a breakpoint in `getProductInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question, because i found a solution using another code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    var product_id: NSString?;

    @IBOutlet weak var lastmanstandingButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var upgradeProButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        product_id = "com.mi.yaya.inapp1";
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        lastmanstandingButton.enabled = false
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func upgradeProButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        buyConsumable()
    }

    func buyConsumable(){
        println("About to fetch the products");
        // We check that we are allow to make the purchase.
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
            var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            println("Fething Products");
        }else{
            println("can't make purchases");
        }
    }

    // Helper Methods

    func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
        println("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
        var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

    }


    // Delegate Methods for IAP

    func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        println("got the request from Apple")
        var count : Int = response.products.count
        if (count>0) {
            var validProducts = response.products
            var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as! SKProduct
            if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
                println(validProduct.localizedTitle)
                println(validProduct.localizedDescription)
                println(validProduct.price)
                buyProduct(validProduct);
            } else {
                println(validProduct.productIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            println("nothing")
        }
    }


    func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("La vaina fallo");
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)    {
        println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    println("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                case .Failed:
                    println("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                    // case .Restored:
                    //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Source from: https://github.com/ivanacostarubio/swift-in-app-purchase-example

I tested on my device and gave me output:

```
About to fetch the products
Fething Products
got the request from Apple
Upgrade PRO
Oppgradere til PRO å få alle funksjoner, fjerne annonser og få fremtidige betalingsoppdateringer gratis.
19
Sending the Payment Request to Apple
Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple
Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple
Product Purchased
```

Answer (score 0):

Potential reasons:

1. Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
2. Do you have a iTunes Paid Application contract in effect?
3. Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?
4. Are there any contracts waiting for approval?
5. In-App Purchases have all fields filled (including screenshots)?
6. Did you wait 24 hours?
7. Using a real device (not a simulator)?
8. Are you using the full product ID in register?
9. Are there any error in your product ID?
10. Do you wait cordova's "deviceready" event before loading the purchases?
11. Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary?
12. Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
13. Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?
14. Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile?
15. Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?
16. Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling?
17. Is your device jailbroken? If so, you need to revert the jailbreak for IAP to work.